# Oncotic (Osmotic Pressure) in the blood pressure

Tags: blood-circulation, osmosis

I just wanted to ask, why is the oncotic pressure more negative in the blood plasma even though the hydrostatic pressure is higher since the blood comes from the pumping of the heart?